# ASP.Net Server Control with a GridView control as a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I'm creating a custom server control that works in conjunction with a GridView control.  I have the following bit of code within my server control that defines the GridView control:

```
[Category("Data")]
[Description("The associated GridView control")]
public GridView GridViewControl { get; set; }
```

When I am in the designer and I drag and drop my control onto the surface and look at its properties in the property window I can see where it says "GridViewControl" and next to it where I can type the ID of a GridView control there is a dropbox from which I can select a GridView control that is already part of the page.  Selecting a GridView control from the dropbox genterates the following code:

```
<cc1:MyCustomControl runat="server" ID="MyCustomControl1" GridViewControl="GridView1" />
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" ...
```

So everything looks good at design time.  However if I try to run the code then the app crashes because it is unable to convert the string name "GridView1" into a reference to the object GridView1.

I'm assuming that this is because I'm missing some sort of code that I need to include in my custom server control code but I haven't been able to find any examples of such a server control.  Is this indeed my problem or is there something else or more that I'm missing in my code for things to work properly at run-time?

Comment: Despite the designer's behavior, I don't think this is actually supported. You can instead create a `GridViewControlID` string property that's decorated with `[IDReferenceProperty(typeof(GridView))]`, and IntelliSense will list of IDs of GridView controls in the source editor. Unfortunately, the Properties window will show just a text box instead of a drop-down.

Comment: So then in a GridView control how does the DataSourceID property work?  In the designer it works with a dropdown, and at runtime it access the datasource object and not just the string name of the datasource?

Comment: The ASP.NET team implemented a whole [GridViewDesigner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.webcontrols.gridviewdesigner(v=vs.110).aspx) class.